# Arrange element right

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://test.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

I want to make this change

http://i61.tinypic.com/296f3g4.png

Code HTML:

```
<div id="main">

                  <div id="linie">

                         <div id="logo-theme">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                                 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/LOGO.png'; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" />
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div id="text-logo">
                        <h1>CABINET AVOCAT CODOBAN</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div id="square">

                        </div>

                 </div>

</div>
```

Code CSS:

```
  #square
    {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:url(img/BODY-CONTACT.png)




}
#linie
{
display:inline-block;
}




#logo-theme{margin-top:200px;class="img-responsive" display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;}


#text-logo{text-transform:uppercase;font-size:15px;color:#fff;margin-top:30px;}
```

We found some examples on the internet and I tried but did not work ... Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is not going to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply these css on your #square:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 200px;
```